# Server opens Stored Procedure like Unicode

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

As you can see in the image bellow, my SQL Stored Procedures, somehow, my SQL Server opens Procedures like Unicode SPs.
That was not the case before, and I have no idea how this apeared now.

I have around 5.000 stored procedures so there is no chance I can edit it manualy.
My SPs starts from `ALTER PROCEDURE` , everything before that is somehow added.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SP's will still work just fine. This is just the way SQL Server Management Studio scripts the objects when you want to generate ALTER- or CREATE-statements.

To change this behavior, go to **Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting**

Set the option "**Include IF NOT EXISTS clause**" to "**False**".

(In other versions of SQL Server Management Studio the option might be called something like "Check for object existence")

Comment: That helped. Thank you very much, we were strugling with this thing for couple of weeks.  
Yes, the procedures worked with this also, but it was really painfull to make some changes on them since everything was all RED :)

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, changing the scripting option "**Include IF NOT EXISTS clause**" to false solves the problem. To add context, if this value is ***true***, it has to be scripted by putting the entire Alter Procedure statement in an @statement variable, because the conditional logic associated with the check for existence requires the ALTER PROCEDURE statement be inside a BEGIN/END block, which is not allowed. So Microsoft's workaround is to put the entire ALTER PROCEDURE statement in the @statement variable, which is executed conditionally inside a BEGIN/END block.